# How to limit bandwidth of file upload?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to upload a file to Microsoft Azure server using their Android mobile services. But the problem is during upload, a single file upload eats off all the available bandwidth.

Is there any way to limit bandwidth of single upload?

**What I have tried?**

Azure service can take files in chunks. So I defined chunk size to 50kb and max bandwidth limit per connection is 100kb/s

```
{
  t1=geTimeInMilliseconds();
  uploadChunk();
  t2=geTimeInMilliseconds();
  t3=t2-t1;
  if(t3<500ms){
   sleep(500-t3);
  }
}
```

I am sure this is not the perfect way of doing it. Any suggestion on this would be a great help..

Comment: Cant you just write a rate calculator to compute your upload rate at client side?

Comment: @AlexSuo  I am doing that only rt?  or You mean some thing else has to be done? Can you please elaborate.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the principle of I/O streaming, the simple thinking of the bandwidth limit for uploading as follow.

1. Assumption for the speed limit of I/O streaming is `M Byte/sec`, then the cost time of sending the `N Byte` data is `N/M sec`.
2. Assumption for sending the `N Byte` data at now, then the cost time should be `N/M s`. However, the actual cost time is `T s`, so the sending thread should sleep `(N/M - T) sec` for implementing the limit speed.

Here is a sample code in Java as reference.

```
int BUF_SIZE = 1024;
long speed = 12800L; // 100 Kbit/s = 100 * 1024 / 8 Byte/s = 12800 Byte/s
File file = new File("<file path>");
OutputStream outs = ...;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
long cur = 0L;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while((n = fin.read(buf)) != -1) {
    cur += n;
    out.write(buf);
    if(cur > speed) {
        long idleTime = (cur-speed)*1000/speed;
        Thread.sleep(idleTime);
        cur = 0;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
fin.close();
outs.flush();
outs.close();
```

Comment: In my solution if I reduce the chunk size to a byte it will be same solution as yours rt? or will there be any overheads?

Comment: @Praveen Yes theoretically, but it's not a good idea for using hardware like disk & memory. It's low efficiency.

Comment: this method I can follow only if I am sending to some outputstream. Is there any way to do this while uploading using some third party api like Azure..

Comment: @Praveen For using Azure Storage SDK to upload files, I think you can refer to the JavaDoc of Azure Storage SDK http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/. As example, you can use the `BlobOutputStream` thru the method `openOutputStream` of Class `CloudBlockBlob`.

Comment: Trying to implement it now but have some confusion- What is n(Hope it is an int), what is temp and Where did you use startTime?

Comment: @Praveen The 'n' is an int that is the number of bytes readed from FileInputStream and filled into the buffer. It equals or be less than the size of `buf`. Sorry for my typo mistake, the `temp` is the `buf` that I fixed it. The `startTime` is not necessary that be used in my origin code.

Comment: @ Peter Pan - MSFT  Thanks It uploads file in allotted time but the problem is it still consumes whatever the bandwidth is available